# Downgrading React Native Project from 0.64 to 0.63.4

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

My project is built using React Native 0.64 and hence supports min Android SDK Version 21 and will run on devices only Android 5.0 and above.
But I need my app to run on Android 4.4 devices as well which mean I need to set minSdkVersion to 19, which is not supported in react Native 0.64 but in React Native 0.63.4.

I'm unable to find a concrete solution on how to downgrade RN version.
Please advise and provide with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a new empty React Native project with version 0.63.4.

Then you can move your existing code to the generated empty project and it usually should just work.

Comment: Since the project very big and is now complete, moving files to a new project will require a lot of effort and re-configuration and I would consider this as the last resort.  Is there any legitimate way that is provided like using React Native CLI or any other well Documented official way to achieve the downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually change the **minSdkVersion** from the android project-level build.gradle file to provide support for the android 4.4 version.

Like.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
        minSdkVersion = 19
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**But,** Keep in mind that you must have to test all the libraries working properly after changes are made.

Comment: This does not work.
As mentioned earlier, RN 0.64 has a minSdkVersion of 21 and manually changing this to 19 causes a build error  as follows : 

Error:
        uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.0]

 Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 19,
                or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
                or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook.react" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)